# awk multiple conditions output order

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to format a text file with awk. The text file looks something like this:

```
[----aaa1----]
**************************something1
**************************text1
**************************blabla1
[----aaa2----]
**************************something2
**************************text2
**************************blabla2
[----aaa3----]
**************************something3
**************************text3
**************************blabla3
```

I am using this awk command

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 1 {print | "rev | cut -c6- | rev | cut -c6-" } \
NR % 4 == 2 {print | "cut -c27-" } NR % 4 == 3 {print | "cut -c27-" } \
NR % 4 == 0 {print | "cut -c27-" }' so_test.txt
```

And I expect an output like this:

```
aaa1
something1
text1
blabla1
aaa2
something2
text2
blabla2
aaa3
something3
text3
blabla3
```

but instead I get this:

```
something1
text1
blabla1
something2
text2
blabla2
something3
text3
blabla3
aaa1
aaa2
aaa3
```

can someone please tell me why and how to fix it?

**EDIT**
Let me clarify, the actual file I want to format is a few thousand lines long and the data differs from the one given as example. I can't filter by special characters, because the data in the file contains special characters and such. Basicaly every 4 lines follow this pattern

```
[92m/File/Path/here[00m
FileId                    0B01O-JsvW0LMDaI1B1RYOTQ1NVE  
ModTime                   2016-03-30 12:12:29 +0000 UTC 
LastModifyingUsername     User Name
```

Comment: You can do this all in awk without using other processes, no need for the pipes(which are incidentally why all your output is messed up)

Comment: So you want to print from 6th to 10th character in lines 4K+1 and from character 27th to the end in the rest of cases?

Comment: I want to cut the `[92m` and `[00m` from the nth line and cut first 26 characters from every n+1, n+2 and n+3 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to use `substr` to print from a certain character:

```
awk 'NR%4==1{print substr($0,6, 4); next} {print substr($0, 27)}' file
```

This prints from the 6th character up to to the 10th when the line is on the form 4N+1. For the rest, it prints from the 27th until the end.

It returns:

```
aaa1
something1
text1
blabla1
aaa2
something2
text2
blabla2
aaa3
something3
text3
blabla3
```

From [awk manual -> strings](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html):

> *substr(string, start, length)*
>
> This returns a length-character-long substring of string, starting at
>   character number start. The first character of a string is character
>   number one. For example, substr("washington", 5, 3) returns "ing". If
>   length is not present, this function returns the whole suffix of
>   string that begins at character number start. For example,
>   substr("washington", 5) returns "ington". This is also the case if
>   length is greater than the number of characters remaining in the
>   string, counting from character number start.

Comment: I finally got that working using this syntax: `awk 'NR % 4 == 1 {print substr($0,6,length()-4); next} {print substr($0, 27)}' sorted_folder_index.txt`

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

```
sed  -nr '1~4{s/^.{4}//;s/.{4}$//p};1~4!{s/^.{26}//p}' file
```

When line number is 1,5,9.. `1~4` remove first and last four characters from the line and print line.
Else `1~4!` remove first 26 characters from the line then print.